# How to expand a column in a dataframe following another column's formatting?

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a huge dataframe consisting of 10 mio objects with the following format in RStudio.

```
       ID      DATE        reading
    100845 2014-08-17 0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,0
    100845 2014-08-18 0,0,4,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,1
    100845 2014-08-19 0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,2,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,1,1,0
    100918 2015-07-02 1,0,0,1,0,1,3,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1
    100920 2013-02-07 0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,5,6,4,2,1,0,1
    100920 2013-02-08 0,1,0,0,1,3,5,4,2,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,3,7,5,1,1,1,0
```

The 24 readings per row refer to hourly meter readings during a day. I would like to convert the daily dates to hourly and convert the strings of readings to a column format instead. The IDs should follow this format.
For example, I have implemented the following:

```
hourly <- data.frame(Hourly=seq(min(as.POSIXct(paste0(df$date, "00:00"),tz="")),max(as.POSIXct(paste0(df$date, "23:00"),tz="")),by="hour"))
```

How can I fill in the new fields that are created due to the hourly setting with the same IDs as in the daily format? As the full dataset I have is extremely big, I would appreciate a solution that can run very fast.

Comment: Is the complete dataframe loaded into memory? Then its not bigdata.

Comment: I run this on to R server and I experience many problems with allocation of memory and R crashing due to the size of the tables..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to the speed of this approach on a data set as large as yours, but I think this code does the steps you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  # use separate to spread the readings across separate columns
  separate(reading, into = paste0("hour.", seq(24)), sep = ",") %>%
  # use gather to convert that wide data frame into a long one
  gather(key = hour, value = reading, hour.1:hour.24) %>%
  # make the hour marker into a number
  mutate(hour = as.numeric(gsub("hour.", "", hour)) - 1) %>%
  # order the data
  arrange(ID, DATE, hour) %>%
  # create a new column that combines the date and time stamp
  mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(DATE, hour), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")) %>%
  # shed unneeded columns
  select(ID, datetime, reading)
```

Result:

```
> head(df2)
      ID            datetime reading
1 100845 2014-08-17 00:00:00       0
2 100845 2014-08-17 01:00:00       0
3 100845 2014-08-17 02:00:00       0
4 100845 2014-08-17 03:00:00       0
5 100845 2014-08-17 04:00:00       3
6 100845 2014-08-17 05:00:00       0
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, but there are two issues in my setup. The first hour of every new day that is created has a blank reading and also the readings that were not integers have not been correctly read. How could I fix this?

Comment: If you want a solution that fits your exact situation, you need to post sample data that has all the features of your data. The data you posted didn't include either of those features.

Comment: in the separate command, the sep="," is missing. Now it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for catching and commenting on that missing bit. I will update the answer.